# Caja / Apps Scripts jQuery $(document).ready not firing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

I have a project in Apps Scripts where the code in my $(document).ready never gets executed. I also tried with this basic code at http://caja.appspot.com/, which also doesn't work.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("span").text("Working");
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <span>Not Working</span>
  </body>
</html>​
```

The "Not Working" text shows up. Also tried with jQuery versions 2.x.x

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works if you use a slightly older jQuery version.

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("span").text("Working");
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <span>Not Working</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why, since the documentation says Caja works with all recent jQuery versions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#jquery_and_jquery_ui

Comment: that's odd, here's my test script, works for me: https://script.google.com/d/1FRalblFy-GgzcvXa3O2gAE31EaBcUIOXMrSguAPk106emqNvRuBiqVZ_/edit?usp=sharing